# CMake error with linking Xerces library with Geant4

Tags: c++, cmake, xerces

I have a problem with CMake about linking Xerces.
I see almost post and question in stackoverflow and other forum about it, but none of them works for me.

```
project(DRsim)

option(WITH_GEANT4_UIVIS "Build example with Geant4 UI and Vis drivers" OFF)
if(WITH_GEANT4_UIVIS)
  find_package(Geant4 REQUIRED ui_all vis_all)
else()
  find_package(Geant4 REQUIRED)
endif()

include(${Geant4_USE_FILE})

include_directories(
  ${HEPMC_DIR}/include
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${Geant4_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${XERCESC_DIR}/include
)
file(GLOB sources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cc)
file(GLOB headers ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hh)

add_executable(DRsim DRsim.cc ${sources} ${headers})
target_link_libraries(
  DRsim ${Geant4_LIBRARIES}
  ${HEPMC_DIR}/lib64/libHepMC3.so
  ${HEPMC_DIR}/lib64/libHepMC3rootIO.so
  rootIO
  ${XERCESC_DIR}/lib/libxerces-c.a
)

file(GLOB DRsim_MACROS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.mac)
file(COPY ${DRsim_MACROS} DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

install(TARGETS DRsim DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES ${DRsim_MACROS} DESTINATION .)
```

Here is my CMakeList.txt and below is the error I get after generating with ccmake.

```
 WARNING: Target "DRsim" requests linking to directory "/cvmfs/sft.cern.ch/lcg/releases/XercesC/3.2.2-cfd67/x86_64-slc6-gcc8-opt/lib".  Targets may link only to
 libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
```

Please give me any comments.

Comment: "Please give me any comments." - Looks like you have specified given directory - `/cvmfs/sft.cern.ch/lcg/releases/XercesC/3.2.2-cfd67/x86_64-slc6-gcc8-opt/lib` - as a value of `Geant4_LIBRARIES` or some other variable. CMake explains you why this is wrong: **library** is a **file**, not a *directory*.

Comment: Thank you for a comment! You mean that lib directory path for Xerces is already set to other path setting. Thus `${XERCESC_DIR}/lib/libxerces-c.a` does not work well. Let me check it.